# How to set datatype of an image in java jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using java8 I want to set data type for image. I use `BufferedImage`
for image, but when I call it in my view it is not able to find. I get
an unwanted error.

I get error particular at this line `ps.setBlob(3, ce.getClogo());` in `CompaniesEntity.java`

```
package com.main.demo.EPOSystem.Model;
    
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class CompaniesEntity {
    private int cid;
    private String cname;
    private BufferedImage clogo;
    private String ccordinate;
    private String cphyadd;
    private String ccity;
    private int czipcode;
    private String cstate;
    private String ccountry;

}
```

**CompaniesDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.main.demo.EPOSystem.Viee;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.main.demo.EPOSystem.Model.CompaniesEntity;
import com.main.demo.EPOSystem.connection.EPOConnectionUtil;

public class CompaniesDAOImpl implements CompaniesDaoI {
    private Connection con;
    private PreparedStatement ps;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private int result;
    private CompaniesEntity ce;

    public int addCompany(CompaniesEntity ce) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            con=EPOConnectionUtil.getConnection();
            ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into company values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setInt(1, ce.getCid());
            ps.setString(2, ce.getCname());
            ps.setBlob(3, ce.getClogo());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: What error do you get?